# fire an event programatically every some seconds using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, client-server

My server wants to say "hi" to the clients every interval of time. I have this example of code to demonstrate the event firing according to interval of time. 
But sadly it is not working.

**server :**

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
     io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
     fs = require('fs');


    app.listen(8001);



     function handler(req, res) {
     fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client1.html', function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading client1.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);
    });
  }

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("runing time");

    socket.emit( "clientMessage","hi from server");
    socket.on('clientMessage', function () {
        socket.emit( "serverMessage","hi from server");
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("disconnecting");
    });
  });
```

**Client :**

```
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

   <script>
   var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8001");
   socket.on('connection', function(socket) {


       // *this line is not reached*
        alert("connected")

      sendTestMessage()

    socket.on("serverMessage", function(d) {
        alert("server Message : " + d)
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        alert("disconnected")
    });

   });


   function sendTestMessage() {
    alert("test")
    socket.emit('clientMessage', "Test Message From Client");
    setTimeout(sendTestMessage(), 5000)
   }

  </script>
```

Please any help why ?

Comment: So everything works except the timeout part? If so, try making socket a global variable (simply remove var in front of it). I suspect that this might be scope issue. When setTimeout executes the function, it has no idea what "socket" is. 

Also make sure you have developer console opened, it'll tell you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but it does not work and the console is empty except from **XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8001/socket.io/1/?t=1394890934928"**

Comment: I added alert("connected") in the on("connection"....   scope but it is not working too

Comment: if socket is properly connected to server, try `setInterval` instead of timeout..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be here:

```
setTimeout(sendTestMessage(), 5000)
```

Looks like you are calling the function, but just need to pass a reference instead.

Try:

```
setTimeout(sendTestMessage, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

events on server side and client side should be same.
you should try this
server.js:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("runing time");

setInterval(()=>{
socket.emit("clientMessage","hi from server")
}, 1000)

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("disconnecting");
});
```

client.js:

```
socket.on('connect',()=>{console.log('socket connected')});

socket.on('disconnect',()=>{console.log('socket disconnected')});

socket.on('clientMessage', (msg)=>{
   console.log('Message From Server: ', msg)
});
```

this will emit message from server after every second to client.